# How do I choose a certain object by a number?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Like this:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>
```

I would only like that the second div onClick event turn red color, I know the method first-child, but I want something more especific like div[1] how can I do this?

Comment: [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)  index starts from `1`

or [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)  index starts from `0`

or `:nth()` it is same as `:eq()`

or [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('div:nth-child(2)').click(function(){ // or  $('div:eq(1)').click(function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: For performance reasons it's best to avoid using jQuery pseudo-selectors, they're very slow compared to the `.eq()` method http://jsperf.com/jquery-eq-method-vs-eq-pseudo-selector

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use only jQuery, use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('div').eq(1).on('click',function(){
    $(this).css({color:'red'});
});
```

Or you can combo it with CSS by creating a class:

```
.RedClicked {
    color:red;
}
```

And using the same click event:

```
$('div').eq(1).on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('RedClicked');
});
```

I recommend the latter, as it makes the CSS applied far more reusable.

Comment: Not if you name the class 'red' though ;-)

Comment: i just pulled that name out of my ass, but "red" is a terrible classname haha.

Answer (score 0):

there are diffrant ways

```
$('div').eq(1)// will select <div>World</div>
```

or you can use

```
   $( "div:nth-child(1)" ) // will select <div>Hello</div>
```

or just (although i wont recommend this)

```
$($('div')[1]) // same as .eq
```

Comment: the last one selects the pure javascript object, not the jQuery object. it is not the same as eq.

Comment: sorry i meant the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use css nth-child()
This selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

EG: [click](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child)

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-child(1)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body> 
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>    

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```